# C++, Libsodium sodium_malloc generates an exception

Tags: c++, libsodium

I am reallizing a small code in C++ to cryptograph and decrypt messages, to do this I use Libsodium.

Since the length of the text is not constant I have to make use of dynamic memory, and to cope with the safety of the data allocated in memory I make use of the sodium_malloc function.

After writing my code I tested it, but at the point where I allocate memory with sodium_malloc it generates an exception for me, here is an excerpt:

```
int main()
{
     unsigned char* text;
     text = (unsigned char*)sodium_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (12)); // hello worold --> lenth: 11 + 1 ('\0')

     sodium_free(text);

     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

It generates this exception for me:

```
Unhandled Exception in 0x00007FFDBE61286E (ucrtbase.dll) in DEF (Console).exe: Exit was requested from the program causing an unrecoverable error.
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google finds [this](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/555)

From that 'bug report' we get this

> The library must be initialized with sodium_init() before any other
> function is called.